# Kotlin 1.5.10, Gradle 7.0.2_2 - Could not find method testCompile() group=org.junit.jupiter, name=junit-jupiter-api, version=5.7.2

Tags: java, kotlin, gradle, junit5

After following: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-46090

I'm still issues with:

> > Configure project : POM relocation to an other version number is not fully supported in Gradle : xml-apis:xml-apis:2.0.2 relocated to
> > xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2. Please update your dependency to directly
> > use the correct version 'xml-apis:xml-apis:1.0.b2'. Resolution will
> > only pick dependencies of the relocated element.  Artifacts and other
> > metadata will be ignored.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - Where: Build file '/Users/NOTiFY/IdeaProjects/GoStopHandle/build.gradle' line: 53
> - What went wrong: A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GoStopHandle'.
>
> > Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [{group=org.junit.jupiter, name=junit-jupiter-api, version=5.7.1}] on
> > object of type
> > org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Gradle:

```
plugins {
    id "war"
    id "ear"
    id "idea"

//    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.4.32"
//    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.4.32"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm" version "1.5.0"
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.plugin.jpa" version "1.5.0"

    // Static Code Checkers x 4
    id "checkstyle"

    id "com.github.spotbugs" version "4.7.1"

    id "pmd"
    id "org.sonarqube" version "3.1.1"

    id "org.wildfly.build.provision" version "0.0.11"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.13

repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    //noinspection MultipleRepositoryUrls
    maven {
        name "jboss-nexus"
        url "http://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public/"
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/groups/public-jboss"
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories"
        url "https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/thirdparty-releases"
        //url "http://repository.primefaces.org"
        url "https://repository.primefaces.org"
    }

    jcenter()

    flatDir {
        dirs "lib"
    }
}

checkstyle {
    //toolVersion "8.42"
    toolVersion "8.41.1"
    configFile = file("config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml")
}

dependencies {
    // JUnit 5 (Jupiter) 5.7.1 Feb, 2021
    testCompile group: "org.junit.jupiter", name: "junit-jupiter-api", version: "5.7.1"
    testCompile group: "org.junit.jupiter", name: "junit-jupiter-engine", version: "5.7.1"
    testCompile group: "org.junit.vintage", name: "junit-vintage-engine", version: "5.7.1"
    testCompile group: "org.junit.jupiter", name: "junit-jupiter-params", version: "5.7.1"

    // org.slf4j 25/08/2020
    testCompile group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-nop", version: "1.7.30"
    testCompile group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-simple", version: "1.7.30"
    testCompile group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-jdk14", version: "1.7.30"

    // JBoss Weld 3.1.5.Final CDI 2.0
    //compile group: "org.jboss.weld.se", name: "weld-se-core", version: "4.0.0.Final"
    //compile group: "org.jboss.weld.se", name: "weld-se-core", version: "3.1.6.Final"
    compile group: "org.jboss.weld.module", name: "weld-web", version: "3.1.5.Final"

    compile group: "javax.ejb", name: "javax.ejb-api", version: "3.2.2"
    compile group: "org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb", name: "jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec", version: "2.0.0.Final"

    compile group: "org.eclipse.persistence", name: "javax.persistence", version: "2.2.1"
    compile group: "javax.inject", name: "javax.inject", version: "1"

    compile group: "javax.faces", name: "javax.faces-api", version: "2.3"
    compile group: "javax.enterprise", name: "cdi-api", version: "2.0.SP1"

    // 09/12/20 - Fix pom -> Gradle for
    compile group: "com.sun.xml.bind", name: "jaxb-impl", version: "3.0.0"
    compile group: "javax.xml.bind", name: "jaxb-api", version: "2.3.1"

    // 3 x Hibernate Feb, 2021
    compile group: "org.hibernate", name: "hibernate-core", version: "5.4.31.Final"
    compile group: "org.hibernate", name: "hibernate-entitymanager", version: "5.4.31.Final"
    compile group: "org.hibernate", name: "hibernate-commons-annotations", version: "3.2.0.Final"

    compile group: "org.hibernate", name: "hibernate-search-orm", version: "5.11.8.Final"
    compile group: "org.hibernate.ogm", name: "hibernate-ogm-mongodb", version: "5.4.1.Final"
    // 10/10/2020 x 3
    compile group: "org.jboss.resteasy", name: "resteasy-jaxrs", version: "3.14.0.Final"

    compile group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", name: "httpclient", version: "4.5.13"
    compile group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", name: "httpcore", version: "4.4.13"

    // Omnifaces + WEB-INF 2021-01-24 16:49
    compile group: "org.omnifaces", name: "omnifaces", version: "3.11"

//    compile group: "org.primefaces", name: "primefaces", version: "10.0.1"
    implementation group: 'org.primefaces', name: 'primefaces', version: '10.0.1'

    compile group: "org.primefaces.themes", name: "bootstrap", version: "1.0.10"

    // mongodb - 6 February 2021
    compile group: "org.mongodb", name: "mongo-java-driver", version: "3.12.8"

    compile group: "com.google.code.gson", name: "gson", version: "2.8.6"
    compile group: "javax.ws.rs", name: "javax.ws.rs-api", version: "2.1.1"
    compile group: "org.slf4j", name: "slf4j-api", version: "1.7.30"

    // Kotlin - 21-05-05
//    compile group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name: "kotlin-stdlib", version: "1.4.32"
    compile group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name: "kotlin-stdlib", version: "1.5.0"

    // JSoup Java HTML Parser - 01/03/2020
    compile group: "org.jsoup", name: "jsoup", version: "1.13.1"

    // JUnit Jupiter
    //compile group: "org.junit.platform", name: "junit-platform-commons", version: "1.3.2"
    //compile group: "org.opentest4j", name: "opentest4j", version: "1.1.1"

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.picketlink/picketlink-idm-parent
    //compile group: "org.picketlink", name: "picketlink-idm-parent", version: "2.5.5.SP12", ext: "pom"

    providedCompile "javax.ejb:javax.ejb-api:3.2.2"
    //providedCompile "org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb:jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec:1.0.1.Final"
    providedCompile group: "org.jboss.spec.javax.ejb", name: "jboss-ejb-api_3.2_spec", version: "2.0.0.Final"
    providedCompile "org.eclipse.persistence:javax.persistence:2.2.0"
    providedCompile "javax.inject:javax.inject:1"

    providedCompile "javax.faces:javax.faces-api:2.3"

    providedCompile group: "javax.enterprise", name: "cdi-api", version: "2.0.SP1"
    providedCompile group: "javax.servlet", name: "javax.servlet-api", version: "4.0.1"

    // Hibernate - Feb, 2021
    providedCompile "org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.28.Final"
    providedCompile "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:5.4.28.Final"

    // org.hibernate:hibernate - Mar, 2010
    providedCompile "org.hibernate:hibernate-commons-annotations:3.2.0.Final"
    providedCompile "org.hibernate:hibernate-search-orm:5.11.8.Final"

    providedCompile "org.jboss.resteasy:resteasy-jaxrs:3.14.0.Final"

    providedCompile "com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6"
    providedCompile "org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.30"
    providedCompile "javax.ws.rs:javax.ws.rs-api:2.1.1"

    spotbugsPlugins "com.h3xstream.findsecbugs:findsecbugs-plugin:1.11.0"
}

checkstyleMain {
    source = ["src/main/java"]
}

spotbugs {
    ignoreFailures = true
    toolVersion = "4.2.3"
    reportsDir = file("reports/spotbugs")
    effort = "max"
    reportLevel = "high"

    // ignoreFailures = false
    // showProgress = true
    // effort = "default"
    // reportLevel = "default"
    // visitors = [ "FindSqlInjection", "SwitchFallthrough" ]
    // omitVisitors = [ "FindNonShortCircuit" ]
    // reportsDir = file("$buildDir/ƒprime")
    // includeFilter = file("include.xml")
    // excludeFilter = file("exclude.xml")
    // onlyAnalyze = [ "com.foobar.MyClass", "com.foobar.mypkg.*" ]
    // maxHeapSize = "1g"
    // extraArgs = [ "-nested:false" ]
    // jvmArgs = [ "-Duser.language=ja" ]
}

pmd {
    ignoreFailures = true
    reportsDir = file("reports/pmd")
    ruleSets = [
            "java-basic",
            "java-braces",
            "java-clone",
            "java-codesize",
            "java-comments",
            "java-controversial",
            "java-coupling",
            "java-design",
            "java-empty",
            "java-finalizers",
            "java-imports",
            "java-optimizations",
            "java-strictexception",
            "java-strings",
            "java-typeresolution",
            "java-unnecessary",
            "java-unusedcode"
    ]
}

tasks.withType(Pmd) {
    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }
}

tasks.withType(Checkstyle) {
    reports {
        html.destination rootProject.file("reports/checkstyle/checkstyle.html")
    }
}

task deleteFiles(type: Delete) {
    project.logger.lifecycle(">>>>> 1 deleteFiles")

    delete fileTree("./build/libs") {
        include "**/GoStopHandle*.?ar"
    }

    delete fileTree("./src/main/application") {
        include "**/GoStopHandle*.war"
        include "**/GoStopHandle*.jar"
        include "**/GoStopHandle*.ear"
    }
}

task GoStopHandleWAR(type: War) {
    project.logger.lifecycle(">>>>> 2 GoStopHandleWAR")

    dependsOn deleteFiles

    archiveName "GoStopHandleWAR.war"
    //archiveFileName "GoStopHandleWAR.war"

    //webInf {
    //    from "WEB-INF"
    //}

    rootSpec.exclude("**/dto/*")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/ean/*")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/ejb/*")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/entity/*")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/filter/*")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/gson/*")
    //rootSpec.exclude("**/omnifaces/*")

    rootSpec.exclude("**/controller/*")

    // Exclude push PushEvent.class
    rootSpec.exclude("**/push/PushEvent.class")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/push/PushEvent.class")

    rootSpec.exclude("**/webservices/*")

    rootSpec.exclude("**/GoStopHandle*.jar")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/GoStopHandle*.war")
}

task GoStopHandleJAR(type: Jar) {
    project.logger.lifecycle(">>>>> 3 GoStopHandleJAR")

    dependsOn GoStopHandleWAR

    archiveName "GoStopHandleJAR.jar"
//    archiveFileName "GoStopHandleJAR.jar"

    from("./src/main/java") {
        include "META-INF/**"
    }

    // Exclude
    rootSpec.exclude("**/jsf/SliderViewBean.class")
    rootSpec.exclude("**/push/PushBean.class")

    from("./build/classes/java/main") {
        include "*/**"
    }

    // Kotlin
    from("./build/classes/kotlin/main") {
        include "*/**"
    }
}

task copyGoStopHandleWAR(type: Copy) {
    project.logger.lifecycle(">>>>> 4 copyGoStopHandleWAR")

    dependsOn GoStopHandleJAR

    from file("./build/libs/GoStopHandleWAR.war")
    into file("./src/main/application")
}

task copyGoStopHandleJAR(type: Copy) {
    project.logger.lifecycle(">>>>> 5 copyGoStopHandleWAR")

    dependsOn copyGoStopHandleWAR

    from file("./build/libs/GoStopHandleJAR.jar")
    into file("./src/main/application")
}

task GoStopHandleEAR(type: Ear) {
    project.logger.lifecycle(">>>>> 6 GoStopHandleEAR")

    apply plugin: "ear"

    dependsOn copyGoStopHandleJAR

    archiveName "GoStopHandle.ear"
//    archiveFileName "GoStopHandle.ear"

    manifest {
        from("./src/main/resources/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF")
    }

    exclude "**/*.class"
    exclude "**/asm-Java.jar"
    exclude "**/jboss-deployment-structure.xml"

    exclude("**/beans.xml")

    dependencies {
        earlib group: "com.google.code.gson", name: "gson", version: "2.8.6", ext: "jar"
        earlib group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", name: "httpclient", version: "4.5.13", ext: "jar"
        earlib group: "org.apache.httpcomponents", name: "httpcore", version: "4.4.13", ext: "jar"

//        earlib group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name: "kotlin-stdlib", version: "1.4.32", ext: "jar"
        earlib group: "org.jetbrains.kotlin", name: "kotlin-stdlib", version: "1.5.0", ext: "jar"
    }
}
```

What is the progress or issues with Kotlin 1.5.0 & JUnit 5.7.1?

TIA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May 19, 2021 upgrade JUnit with 5.7.2_1 still get:

```
What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'GoStopHandle'.
> Could not find method testCompile() for arguments [{group=org.junit.jupiter, name=junit-jupiter-api, version=5.7.2}] on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-api

Migrated:

> compile group: -> implementation group: